# What is this Russian calendar reminder that popped up?

Tags: android, spam

I woke up this morning and saw a calendar reminder that I definitely did not put there, written in Russian. It would be super helpful if anyone knows what the text means, but I figured opening the reminder was a bad idea in case there are any exploits in the Calendar app.

Could my GMail account be compromised? Or maybe some site I visited put that there somehow? Should I be worried?[image]

**EDIT:** I looked at my calendar again and the invitation had been copied to literally every single day of every month on my calendar... that's some aggressive spam. I've changed my default settings to hide invitations I haven't responded to or that I've declined. Hopefully this won't happen again.

Comment: This is just spam and not a compromise. See also [How to Keep Spam Out of Your Google Calendar](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-keep-spam-out-of-your-google-calendar-1835810050)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears to be this: https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/06/22/google-calendar-phising-scam/

> Scammers are exploiting [Google] Calendar['s] default setting, which automatically adds invites to your agenda, even if you haven't accepted them. Even worse, it'll create an automatic reminder to notify you a few minutes before the fake event takes place. [...] The invitation would typically contain a link to collect sensitive data such as your credit card or bank account number. Since the notification comes from an app people tend to trust, they'd pay less attention to its authenticity, which is precisely what attackers want.

The article also mentions how to fix this google calendar bug (ahem, I mean 'feature' of course):

> [to deactivate] automatic event creation[,] head over to Calendar's settings using a computer, navigate to Event Settings -> Automatically add invitations -> No, only show invitations to which I've responded. You can also prevent Calendar from showing declined events in your agenda by going to View Options and deselecting Show declined events.

Comment: Most I've seen are in English which actually makes them more credible.

Comment: Reported as spam first before doing this setting change. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The notification says "Special Message About Money Transfer", and, all things considered, is most likely a phishing attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the translation! I was curious to know what it meant.

Answer (score 0):

This *could be* a phishing attempt. This means, clicking on the links in this event may cause negative effects. But the event itself is harmless; I delete such events from my calendar almost weekly; they all come to one of my gmail addresses, I believe this address did somehow get into a database of Russian spammers.

If this can console you, remember that you are not the target of this spam/phishing campaighn, just a 'collateral damage'. These spammers hunt Russian users, and they make no effort to compromise your account specifically.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a terrible way to try to phish American users. Who sees a link with accompanying foreign language text and thinks "Hey, I should follow this link written in a language I don't know and fill out any personal information it asks for..."?